# Show estimated dispatch date after add to cart form in product page

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce store and I would like to show my customers an estimated dispatch date below the add to cart form. The logic is

1. If the customer places the order by 12PM IST, it would be dispatched by 3-5 Working Days.
2. If the customer places the order after 12PM IST, it would be dispatched by 4-5 Working Days.
3. If the customer places the order on weekends, It should automatically consider it as 3-5 Working Days from Monday.

I tried the [businessbloomer's code](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-show-dispatch-est-shipping-date-single-product/) but my logic is a little complicated so I couldn't get it to work!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You want to show the estimated dispatch before adding the product to cart of after adding ?

Comment: Sorry, my question is a little confusing. Before adding to cart, the hook is after add to cart form. Just to display an estimated dispatch date.

Comment: Ok. got it. Doesn't the timezone should be the user's timezone ? Or your website timezone ?

Comment: It should be website's time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the code below ( Tested and works fine). If you are having issues with incorrect time, see if the timezone is set correct. Based on your query I assume the timezone should be **Kolkatta**.

**Goto Dashboard -> Settings -> General -> Timezone**

```
function dispatch_message(){

    $current_time = current_time('D | H');
    $current_time = explode('|', $current_time );
    $current_day = isset( $current_time[0] ) ? trim( $current_time[0] ) : false;
    $current_hour = isset( $current_time[1] ) ? trim( $current_time[1] ) : false;
  
    $message = '4-5 Working Days.';
    
    if( in_array( $current_day, array( 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun' ) ) ){
        //Weekend
        $message = '3-5 Working Days from Monday.';

    }else if( $current_hour <= "12"){
        //Before 12pm IST
        $message = '3-5 Working Days.';
    }

    ?>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;font-size: 17px;color: red;">
        <b>Est Dispatch Date:</b> <?php echo $message; ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'dispatch_message' );
```

**UPDATE**

You can make changes to the above code inorder to hide the dispatched date for certain categories. Add the if condition as the first line of code as shown below and return inorder to skip the remaining part of function.

```
function dispatch_message(){

    if ( is_product() && has_term( array( 'dress', 'clothing' ), 'product_cat' ) ){
        return;
    }
    
    $current_time = current_time('D | H');
    $current_time = explode('|', $current_time );
    $current_day = isset( $current_time[0] ) ? trim( $current_time[0] ) : false;
    $current_hour = isset( $current_time[1] ) ? trim( $current_time[1] ) : false;

    $message = '4-5 Working Days.';

    if( in_array( $current_day, array( 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun' ) ) ){
        //Weekend
        $message = '3-5 Working Days from Monday.';

    }else if( $current_hour <= "12"){
        //Before 12pm IST
        $message = '3-5 Working Days.';
    }

    ?>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;font-size: 17px;color: red;">
        <b>Est Dispatch Date:</b> <?php echo $message; ?>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'dispatch_message' );
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Although if I wanna hide this to a particular category(s) how can I do that? I have a snippet already but not sure where I need to add it.

`if ( is_product() && has_term( array( 'dress', 'clothing' ), 'product_cat' ) )`

How do I do this?

Comment: There is an extra semicolon after the break tag before php?

Comment: @PavanKumar Ya. A semicolon is there. I have removed it.

Comment: @PavanKumar Regarding hiding the dispatch info for some categories, I have updated the code. Check it

Comment: Thanks for the updated code but it's reflecting on all product categories, were you able to test this? I unfortunately couldn't get it to work for some reason. It shows on all categories, even on Virtual Products.

Comment: @PavanKumar I was not able to test this code. I will do the same and update you

Comment: @PavanKumar I have tested this and this works fine. The message is not shown for products with category `dress` and `clothing`

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working fine now. There was another before add to cart in the functions.php so I changed it to after and then this started working. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: instead of the 3-5 working days from monday and all that can we show the actual day? like "Est Dispatch Date : 28 Oct - 1 Nov"?

Comment: @PavanKumar Have you got it ?

Comment: I was able to show the 3-5 working days text but was unable to show the actual days like "25th November - 1st December" I tried to edit the code a little but it ended up breaking my website so I kinda left it with the default message. Thanks for your help mate!

Comment: Ok. If you want it, let me know

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use php for logic and hook it to needed place in template

```
function add_est_time(){

   //from 0 to 23
   $current_hour = date( 'G', time() );
   //from 0 to 6
   $current_day = date( 'w', time() );

   $message = __('3-5 Working Days', 'textdomain'); 

   if ( $current_hour >= 12) {
     $message = __('4-5 Working Days', 'textdomain');
   }

   if ($current_day >= 5) {
     $message = __('3-5 Working Days from Monday', 'textdomain');
   }

   echo $message;
}

//hook to needed place
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_est_time' );
```

Also you can use JS and replace needed text with this logic.

Comment: I replaced message with this and this seems to be working just fine.
`echo '<div style="clear: both"></div><div style="margin-top: 10px;font-size: 17px;color: red;"><b>Est Dispatch Date:</b> 3 to 5 Working Days.</div><br>';`

It's eastern standard time? It's around 3:30Pm here and it says 3-5 Working days. It ideally should be showing the 2nd condition.

Comment: Time is a current time of WP and setup in site settings. You can also add css class to div and move style to your css file. About timezones - you can set it separately of WP time with one string in function's begin: date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

Comment: Default timezone is set to Kolkata! Both codes work fine, solved my purpose